# existence of the minimizer for a finite dimensional subspace of a normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and let $Y$ be a finite dimensional subspace. If $x \in Y^C$, then we need to prove that there exist $y_0 \in Y$ such that $||x-y_0||= d(x,Y)= \inf_{y\in Y}||x-y||=M$.

My work: by the definition of the infimum, we have for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, an element $y_n\in Y$ such that:

$||x-y_n|| < M +\frac{1}{n}$

but, $ M\leq ||x-y_n||$ thus we let $n\rightarrow \infty$ and we get:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}||x-y_n||=M$.

I need to show that this sequence $\{y_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence by proving that it is bounded. I was able to prove $\{y_n\}$ is bounded, but not sure how to show that it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: $Y$ as finite dimensional normed space, behaves like $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

In a finite-dimensional normed space, closed bounded balls are compact.

Comment: This is correct, so can we say that the sequence lives in a closed bounded ball which is compact, and it must have convergent subsequence!!